# jquery spin not replacing submit button for form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I user the spin.js and jquery.spin plugins to show a spinning icon for ajax submitted items in my web application.

It works great for regular link buttons. However for a submit button it does not show and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code:

Form:

```
=form_for(@resource, :url => add_comment_resource_path, :remote => true) do |f|
                =text_area_tag :comment,nil, :class => "span7", :rows => 3
                =f.submit "Add Comment", :class => "btn authorize spin"
```

JS:

```
//= require spin.min
//= require jquery.spin




    $('.spin').live('click',function(){
        $(this).spin('small');
    });
```

When I click on the submit button a spinning icon should show. I can see on the page the following gets inserted in the html:

```
<input class="btn btn-small authorize spin" name="commit" type="submit" value="Add Comment">
    <div class="spinner" style="position: relative; z-index: 2000000000; left: 537px; top: 950px; " aria-role="progressbar"></input>
```

It seems the spinner icon is being nested inside the input which is why its not showing. How can I get it to show then?

Answer (score 1):

there is a typo, change this:

```
$('.spin').live('click',function(){
```

to:

```
$('.spinner').on('click',function(e){ // you can use `on()` instead of `live()` which is deprecated
   e.preventDefault()
```

Comment: the .spin works fine for other parts of the application and when switching it to spinner nothing changed.  It seems like it won't show over the submit button for some reason.

Comment: @chell try `event.preventDefault()` which prevents default action of the element.